# Dictionary change of order

Tags: c#, dictionary, xamarin

I have a dictionary.

```
  Dictionary<int, string> inboxMessages = new Dictionary<int, string>();
```

This dictionary contains messages with their own unique ID (the newer the message, the higher the ID). I put the messages in a picker (xamarin) but it shows the oldest messages first. How can I change this?

The Picker:

```
 inboxPicker = new Picker
        {
            WidthRequest = 320,
        };
        foreach (string inboxMessage in inboxMessages.Values)
        {
            inboxPicker.Items.Add(inboxMessage);
        }
```

How i get my messages:

```
        private async Task getMessages()
    {
        await Task.Run(async () => {
            MailModel[] mails = await api.GetMails(App.userInfo.user_id);

            foreach (MailModel mail in mails)
            {
                inboxMessages.Add(mail.message_id,mail.sender_user_id +" "+ mail.subject +" "+ mail.time_send);
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should sort the dictionary entries while you still have access to their keys:

```
foreach (string inboxMessage in inboxMessages
    .OrderByDescending(m => m.Key)
    .Select(m => m.Value)
{
    inboxPicker.Items.Add(inboxMessage);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The [`Values` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ekcfxy3x(v=vs.110).aspx) of a dictionary is not ordered. Quote from the documentation:

> The order of the values in the `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>.ValueCollection` is unspecified [...]

If you want to retrieve the values in some specific order, you need to sort it yourself. For example:

```
var sorted = inboxMessages.OrderByDescending(kv => kv.Key).Select(kv => kv.Value);

foreach (string inboxMessage in sorted)
{
    inboxPicker.Items.Add(inboxMessage);
}
```

This retrieves the KeyValuePairs from the dictionary, sorts them descending on their `int` key and then returns an enumeration of the values.

Comment: It says that the Dictionary does not contain a definition for OrderByDesc.

Comment: @JeroenM: Typo, should be `OrderByDescending`. Thanks, fixed.

Comment: Both your and C.Evenhuis's answer work. Accepted the other on first because it worked first. But both answers do the job. Thanks! I have to admit I like it that you explained a bit more.

Comment: @JeroenM: No problem, glad I could help!